# howto use the libcurl by ndk standalone tool chainon on android

Tags: android, c++, linux, c++11, android-ndk

now, i have a question: first of all i already get the ndk standalone tool chain ---arm-linux-androideabi-g++ sucessful; now i have to write a commandline c++ program which will use libcurl to do http requests,  i can successful compile it on my mac( which has the libcurl default? ) use g++, but when i use the arm-linux-androideabi-g++ to compile it, it produce following error:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -std=c++11 -lcurl upload.cpp -o upload

upload.cpp:12:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: no such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

i have a libcurl(include files and .a lib file) which can used in android, so howto configure the arm-linux-androideabi-g++ so that it can compile it successfully? thanks advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you include your header like

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

if you do that, arm-linux-androideabi-g++ searches header file in some specific location. and if arm-linux-androideabi-g++ does  not point same directory with g++, headers can not be found. try to copy just header files of curl to your project, jni/curl folder, and use " instead of <

```
#include "curl/curl.h"
```

if you have right .a file, functions in header files will be pointed to lib file successfully.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i changed to "curl/curl.h" just now, but it has the same error; and i should explain the libcurl more, i just download it, i think it should do same configure, so the arm-linux-androideabi-g++ can find it?

Comment: I am not sure they use same configuration. do you have .h files in downloaded file ? if yes, please copy them to your project (without .c or .cpp files). g++ repository might have already curl headers

Comment: i do that as your said, i copy  the include files(curl.h and all) to the project, it produce flollowing error: **curl/multi.h:131:40: error 'fd_set' has not been declared**

Comment: I think it is related, http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2002-07/0040.html. try to include <sys/time.h> in multi.h

Comment: From what you say, your copy of libcurl does not fit Android toolchain. Note however that libcurl is available on all Android devices. You can download the relevant headers from [googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/curl/).

Comment: @AlexCohn i have solved this problem, just as what Adem said, modify the <curl/curl.h> to "curl/curl.h", add the downloaded libcurl include files to the project, when compile, i include the libcurl.a, it just worked. the "fd_set" is in <sys/select> according to posix.1 2001, it's in <sys/time.h> in earlier standards, whatever, thanks you two